# Trying to bulk update instead of one by one in Laravel 5.2.31

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am using the following code to check all active memberships of the user

```
$UserMemberships = \App\Models\User\Membership\UserMembershipModel
::where('UserID', $UserID)
->where('IsActive', true)
->get();
```

Then I am setting the active status of membership to false one by one.

```
foreach($UserMemberships as $UserMembership) {
    $UserMembership->IsActive = false;
    $UserMembership->save();
}
```

Is there any way to do it in one shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly update record, try this query:

```
$UserMemberships = \App\Models\User\Membership\UserMembershipModel
::where('UserID', $UserID)
->where('IsActive', true)
->update(['IsActive' => false]);
```